# DragDropContext is an invalid component

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to create a `DragDropContext` but failing.

```
var root = <CommentBox url="/metis/api/shifts" pollInterval={2000} />;

var AppDnD = ReactDnD.DragDropContext(ReactDnDMultiBackend.default(RDMBHTML5toTouch.default))(root);

ReactDOM.render(AppDnD, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This gives...

> ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a
>   class like Foo, pass React.createElement(Foo) or .

... in the console.

I thought that decorating a React object results in a new React object. So why doesn't the render method accept this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference between `React component` and `React element`. In the docs of `react-dnd`, it is written that `ReactDnD.DragDropContext` returns a `component` (which means `AppDnD` is a component), but `React.render` expect an `element` as first parameter. So pass an element to `render` method like this

`ReactDOM.render(<AppDnD />, document.getElementById('content'));`

Comment: Yes, that works. But I need to use a `DragDropContext` don't I?

Comment: @IanWarburton I am not sure what do you mean. The docs says that `DragDropContext` returns a wrapped `component`. It does not say element. So you cant directly pass it to render method

Comment: ok. Thanks. Well that has cleared that up. Wherever it goes, it's not there. :)

Comment: How do you explain this... https://github.com/LouisBrunner/react-dnd-multi-backend/blob/master/src/examples/App.js. If you look at index.js (up a level), it uses the  App in the render function, which has been wrapped  by a `DragDropContext`?

Comment: @IanWarburton It is doing exactly what i have told you in answer. In index.js, `App` is a component wrapped by `DragDropContext`. Since it is component, and `render` want an element, it is being rendered as `ReactDOM.render(<App />...`. Hope you got it.

Comment: Oh, I get it. `App` is converted to an element by `<App />`. I should have read your answer more carefully. Thanks.